# strange mysql behaviour on timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Please have a look at this mysql query. What it *should* do is pretty simple - list dates, created from timestamps not older than 10 days.

It works, but not perfectly ...

- If I have only 1 timestamp matching, I have 0 results.
- If I have 2 timestamps matching, I have 1 results.
- if I have 3 timestamps matching, I have 2 results
- ... and so on...

So the newest timestamp in the table is always ignored by the query, WHY ?!

```
$timestamp_now = date('U');
$timestamp_10_day_back = $timestamp_now - 864000;

mysql_select_db("$db_visitors");
$sql = "SELECT DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(visitors_timestamp))
        FROM visitors
        WHERE visitors_timestamp > $timestamp_10_day_back
        ORDER BY visitors_timestamp DESC";
$sql = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    echo $row[0] . "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just remove

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
```

...which is swallowing your first result

Answer (score 1):

First row is being ignored because of the row `$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);` then you call it again in your `while` loop . just remove this row .

Answer (score 0):

try the code following

```
$n=count($row);
if($n>0){
 for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++){
   echo $row[i];}}
```

or

```
print_r($row);
```